# Using $this when not in object context in

Tags: php, yaml

I'm stuck probably at a fairly simple question... I'm working on a implementation with YAML to enable the duplication of the application.

However, setting up the config model is the part where I'm stuck.

```
class ConfigModel {

public $configSection = null;
private $configArray = array();

public function loadYML(){
    $this->configArray = Spyc::YAMLLoad('../config/config.yml');
}

public function setConfigSection($configSection){
    $this->configSection = $configSection;
}

public function getConfig($configSection){

    $this->loadYML(); //Line 33

}
```

}

Through a test script I request the specific contents of the YML file:

```
$mysqlSettings = ConfigModel::getConfig('mysql');
```

But then I'm getting the error: 
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in Line 33

The loadYML works and outputs a Array. And to my onderstanding the this->loadYML(); is allowed to be used there...

Answer (score 0):

You trying to call `ConfigModel::getConfig()` as static method. It is is wrong to use `$this` in static method. You must declare `$configArray` as static property and `loadYML()` and `getConfig()` as static methods if you need to call `getConfig()` as static